# Change datetime format

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have below code :-

```
1) String str = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy")

Output :
str gives "2/3/2014"

2) DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy"));

Output :
dt.ToString() gives "2014/02/03 12:00:00 "
```

But I'm not able to understand why it is not giving "2014/2/3 12:00:00 " ,i.e, without leading zeroes in day and month?

Comment: Because you are now formatting a DateTime value with no format specified, using dt.ToString().

Comment: I want to convert datetime format in dt as 2014/2/3. Is it possible ?

Comment: I want to convert it finally into a datetime and when i convert, it applies leading zeroes in dt.

Comment: Is it possible to get the value in dt as 2014/2/3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default format string for System.DateTime is "G" as in System.DateTime.ToString("G") where G is one of the presets. from [source](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingEvilOverridingSystemDateTimesDefaultToString.aspx)

Edit 1:

```
    Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = new Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

    customCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy/M/d";

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = customCulture;

    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy"));
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString())
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the value in dt as 2014/2/3 ?

Answer (score 5):

DateTime values have no format, it is the [DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ToString%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that outputs your datetime value in a  particular format.

If you don't specify any parameter in the ToString() then the output is formatted using the [general date and time format specifier ('G')](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  (Usually is the one set up in you control panel international settings)

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("M/d/yyyy"));
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the value in dt as 2014/2/3 ?

Comment: Why not: `dt.ToString("yyyy/M/d")`  Well assuming 2 is the month

Answer (score 0):

When using `ToString()` without any format, it simply uses the default `ToString()` method.
Use the format you specified again to get the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Format function for displaying the way you want

```
string.Format("{0:yyyy/M/d}",dateValue);
```

regards

Comment: When i convert it into datetime then it agains applies leading zeroes.